# How to use Powershell to get a websites HostHeader

Tags: powershell, web, iis-7.5, powershell-2.0

I am trying to use powershell to pull hostheaders for any websites installed. Once I have that down, I want to look specifically for hostHeaders only for websites using port 80 and port 443.

So far I was able to use the

`get-webbinding cmdlet`

to pull some information from the website, but I am unsure how to use it to query websites for the HostHeader information. In the output of the get-webbinding command I see the host headers as part of the bindingInformation column, but am unsure how to just get the host header info.

However when I query a website via

`get-webbinding -HostHeader (hostHeaderName)`

I get information back, so I believe there is a way to use get-webbinding to query for only the hostHeader information.

If there is another way to get this information, please let me know. I have also had no luck trying to use

`get-website`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to split the `bindingInformation` on `:` and get the last part:

```
Get-WebBinding | select -expand bindingInformation | %{$_.split(':')[-1]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I was looking for. Does the [-1] always grab the last item from the .split function?

Comment: @colo_joe - Yeah $a[-1] is the last element of array $a, $a[-2] is the second last and so on.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you an object with two properties: Port and HostHeader (per binding information):

```
Get-WebBinding | Where-Object {$_.bindingInformation -match '80|443'} | ForEach-Object{

    $port,$hh = $_.bindingInformation.split(':')[1..2]

    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Port=$port
        HostHeader=$hh
    }
}
```